# import and export ical calendar to full calendar jquery code or php code

Tags: php, jquery, html

I have a Fullcalendar integrated to my site, i want ical calendar, to import to fullcalendar and export fullcalendar events to ical, How to do it

Comment: SO is not a software writing service... You should to [describe the problem](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/254393) and show what has been done so far to solve it

Comment: @MegaTron correct...!

Comment: I think you need to integrate Ical calendar with your fullcalendar right?